# create httpOnly cookie in Angular and Django

Tags: python, django, angular, cookies, cookie-httponly

Am building an app using Django as the backend and Angular as the frontend. I understand that saving authentication token in httpOnly cookies is the safest, great. The real question is how do i do that. Been hearing around that i will need something like a middle man server to do that but i have not the slightest idea. Could anyone kindly point me in the right direction? I would be eternally grateful.

I've tried setting it on django that was when i realized it cannot be set across domain. So pls help

- Angular 5
- python 3.6
- django 1.11

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.py` file set [SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY)=True

Comment: thanks but the angular frontend and the django backend are on different domain so that won't work

Comment: I think you can set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to the angular sites domain